# How do I track the number of reactions on a message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I wanted to implement report&ban system and I decided to use an embedded message with reactions added to it. Moderator can either agree or disagree. For example once 10 moderators agree with the complaint the user mentioned in this message should be banned or kicked.

I thought of using `client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {})`, but it only checks *cached* messages. Then I found discordjs.guide about reactions and they showed how to use `client.on('raw', (event) => {})`, but it's was abandoned long time ago and I didn't even found any mentions about this official Discord.js documentation. Message has `.awaitReactions(filter, [options])`, but I have to mark voting messages somehow and then searching them in a some kind `client` of method which is super complicated.

Here's what I have:

```
const service = client.channels.get('id');
    let user = msg.mentions.users.first();
    if (!user) {
        msg.reply('Couldn\'t find the user!')
        return 1;
    }
    args.shift();
    let reason = args.join(' ').trim();
    if (!reason) {
        msg.reply('No reason to create a complaint!')
        return 1;
    }
    msg.channel.send(`I've created and sent a user complaint about ${user.tag}!)`)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    msg.delete();
    const emb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('User complaint')
        .addField('Who?', `**User: ${user.tag}**`)
        .addField('Reason?', `**Reson: ${reason}**`)
        .setColor('#ff7b00')
        .setFooter('Please take action');
    service.send(emb)
        .then(async msg => {
            await msg.react('✅')
            msg.react('❌')
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error()
            msg.reply('Couldn\'t send a user complaint!');
            return 1;
        })
```

Is it even possible? I explained my previous plan earlier, but is there a way to make is simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Database**

You should use either `message.awaitReactions();` or `client.on('messageReactionAdd', ...);` and fetch the message on the bot `ready` event.

It's a very simple process. You'd require a database to store the message ID's, channel ID and of course, server ID. After that make a small algorithm inyour ready event to go through all the messages collected from the database and use either `message.awaitReactions();` or `client.on('messageReactionAdd', ...);` on them.

I'd suggest using `message.awaitReactions();` if you decide to go with the database method.

**2. Global Array (Less Recommended)**

If you have a really simple bot and you can't use a database then I'd recommend having a global array storing all the message IDs and using those for the `client.on('messageReactionAdd', ...);` event.

You'd have to check if the ID from the message array matches the ID of the message collected in the event and then act accordingly.

This method would work well for the smaller bots, but if you have a bigger, multi-server bot, then I'd highly recommend going with the database version because this version would not work after the bot restarts.

Comment: I love the database thing. Thank you for answer!