# Make a bot react to whatever emoji there is on the message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wish to make the bot react to every reaction there is on an already existing message sent by another user.

For example, I understand it should be something like
`message.react('');`, or something to do with `.then` but I could not find anything useful online regarding this specific issue. Is this possible to do?

Comment: You would have to add a wait after receiving the message as it is not humanly possible to add a reaction before the bot has read the message.

Comment: @Tyler2P Okay, yes, but how do I make the bot see what reactions there are?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57341215/14267427) answer your question?